# TRIM enabled on new Macbook Pro Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: ssd, trim

I'm a newbie with Mac's, so I have a quick question.  Just got a new Macbook Pro with a SSD, and been reading some things about SSD lifespan and enabling TRIM.

In my system properties I have the following:

TRIM Support:   Yes

Seems to me in everything I've read that this means TRIM support is enabled by default and that I do not need to do anything additional to enable this.

Is this correct? Just want to confirm...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Apple documentation, if it says "Yes", than TRIM is supported and enabled.